# how to pause and restart jquery datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to transform a row of my table in a form by clicking a button. My problem is the table uses Datatables plugin, and I would like to disable the script (filtering, sorting ecc.), and reactivate it after submit.

I was trying now to use bDestroy while starting a new istance with filtering and sorting disabled, but I would like to totally disable the script, because it may create new issues to my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I was looking for is fnDestroy(), then you can reinitialize the table when you want, in my case on submit or cancel the form